# How to set the _CheckinComment with CSOM

Tags: client-object-model

I'm looking for a way to set the _CheckinComment.
If i try It like this:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File myUploadFile = myList.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileCreationInformation);
            ListItem myItem = myUploadFile.ListItemAllFields;
            myItem["Title"] = Path.GetFileName(sDocPath);
            myItem["_CheckinComment"] = "This is the comment";
            myClientContext.Load(myItem);
            myClientContext.Load(myUploadFile);
            myClientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

I get Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: ... The field that you want to upgrade, may be write protected.

I want to change the _CheckinComment (InternalName) and not this:

```
myUploadFile.CheckIn("This is the comment", CheckinType.OverwriteCheckIn)
```

Who can help?